# Java Matrix erasing

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to erase every X in a .txt file. When a coordinate is chosen, if it is an `X` is should be replaced with a `0` then also every `X` that is touching it (except diagonally) should be replaced until there are no more `X`'s that can be touched. I'm not getting these results with my current code.

I'm getting this error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9` when I  input in `0` for `getCoord(grid.length, "row")` and `2` for `getCoord(grid[0].length, "column")` in `main()`.

thank you for your help.

### **image1.txt**

```
00X000000
0XXXXXXX0
0X00000XX
0X0X000XX
0X00000X0
0XXXXXXX0
XXXX00XX0
000XX0000
```

### **eraseImage.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 * eraseImage.java
 *
 *  Your Name Goes Here!
 *
 *  will dimension and load a 2-dimensional array of Strings
 *  from a text file.  The first line of the file will contain 
 *  the dimensions of the grid.  Each additional line will have
 *  String made up of 'X's and '0's (that's zeros) to represent
 *  part of an image (X) or a non-image cell(0).
 */

public class eraseImage
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
  String[][] grid = load();
   display(grid);

   do
   {
    int targetRow = getCoord(grid.length, "row");
    int targetCol = getCoord(grid[0].length, "column");
    rubOut(grid, targetRow, targetCol);
    display(grid);
   }
   while(again());

 }

 /**
  *  Please provide documentation here
  */
 public static String[][] load() throws IOException
 {
   BufferedReader innie = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/laxgoalie1996/Desktop/image1.txt"));

   String str = innie.readLine();
   StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(str);
   int rows = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
   int cols = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
   String[][] image = new String[rows][cols];

   for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
   {
    str = innie.readLine();
     for(int col = 0; col < str.length(); col++)
       image[row][col] = str.substring(col, col+1);
     System.out.println(str);
    }

  return image;
 }

 /**
  *  Please provide documentation here
  */
 public static void display(String[][] g)
 {
  System.out.println("\nHere is the current image...\n");
  for (int row = 0; row < g.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < g[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(g[row][column] + " ");}
        System.out.println();}
  System.out.println();
 }

 /**
  *  Please provide documentation here
  */
 public static void rubOut(String[][] g, int tRow, int tCol)
 {
   String str = g[tRow][tCol];
   System.out.println(str);
   if(str.equals("0"))
     return;
   g[tRow][tCol] = "0";

   rubOut(g, tRow, tCol + 1); 
   rubOut(g, tRow, tCol - 1);
   rubOut(g, tRow + 1, tCol); 
   rubOut(g, tRow - 1, tCol);


   return;





 }

 /**
  *  Please provide documentation here
  */
 public static int getCoord(int max, String prompt)
 {
   java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Enter the " + prompt + " number (0 to " + (max-1) + ")  -> ");
   int coord = scan.nextInt();

   while(coord < 0 || coord >= max)
   {
     System.out.print("HEY!  The " + prompt + " number needs to be between 0 and " + (max-1) + "  -> ");
     coord = scan.nextInt();
   }

   return coord;
 }

 /**
  *  Please provide documentation here
  */
 public static boolean again()
 {
  return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: just a thought: it would be helpful to provide the line number which the exception occured?

Comment: the problem is happening at 76,82,84

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to do col < str.length()-1 because when you hit the last column and you are passing col + 1 you are out of bounds

Comment: can you please explain more, where should I put this

Comment: for(int col = 0; col < str.length(); col++)
       image[row][col] = str.substring(col, col+1);

Comment: just put < str.length()-1

Comment: its having no problem loading the txt, the problem is in rubOut

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: In the rubOut(), before each of the last 4 calls to itself, you should check whether `tCol +/- 1` and `tRow +/- 1` would exceed the bound of `g[][]`. If exceeded, just don't call itself.